# Possibility of accessing iPhone user music and videos  

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod

I was wondering if it possible to access iPhone User Music, Videos, Photos and Messages, I am targeting a non `Jailbroken` Devices.

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be going to need this for accessing ipod stuff:

[iPod Library Access Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)